# Where is $f(x) = |x^2 - 3x +2|$ differentiable and where is it $C^1$ and $C^2$.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm a university student taking a real analysis course. We have just started the topic related the question above so I am very new to it and I'm having a little trouble getting off the ground. I am still getting the hang of what $C^1$ and $C^2$ mean and what it means for a  function to be differentiable at some location. It would be awesome if anybody could give me some tips on how to tackle questions like these!

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Take the derivative twice and see what you get. Recall that the absolute value function is defined piecewise: $$\lvert x \rvert = \begin{cases} x & x \geq 0 \\ -x & x < 0 \end{cases}$$ so the derivative will be the piecewise derivative of each piece.

Comment: Is there an $x$ such that $f(x) < 0$? Can you factorise $f$? That might give you an idea where it should differentiable once (and where it certainly shouldn't be).

Comment: It is smooth everywhere except $x=1,x=2$ where $f(x) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The function is defined in the following way

$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
g(x) &\text{ if } x \leq 1 \text{ or } x \geq 2 \\
-g(x) & \text{ if }  x \in [1,2]
\end{cases}.
$$
with $g : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R : x \mapsto g(x) = x^2 - 3x + 2.$  Since $g$ is a polynomial, $f$ is smooth wherever $x\neq 1, x\neq 2.$

When $x = 1$ then we consider the limit of the quotient 
$$  Q_h=\frac {f(1 + h) - f(1)}{h}$$
as $h \to 0$.

If $h < 0$ then

$$ Q_h = \frac{g(1+h)-g(1)}{h} \to g'(1) = - 1. $$

and for $ 1>h >0 $:

$$Q_h = \frac{-g(1 + h)- (-g(1))}{h} \to - g'(1) = 1.$$

Therefore the limit does not exist and $f$ is not differentiable at $x = 1$. You can proceed similarly to show that $f$  is not differentiable at $x = 2$.

Intuitively, when looking at the graph of $f$ near $x= 1$ or $x = 2$ you can see that the graph takes a very sharp (instantaneous) turn so defining a tangent line to the curve at those points cannot be done properly.