# Where is $f(x) = |x^2(x+1)|$ differentiable? And where are they $C^1$ and $C^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, smooth-functions

I'm a maths student taking a real-analysis paper and I'm currently working down my problem sheet. I've been asked the above question.

First I define a piece-wise function to describe the absolute function above.

$$f(x)= \begin{cases} 
       x^2(x+1)  & x \geq -1  \\
      -(x^2)(x+1) & x < -1 \\
   \end{cases}
$$

$$f(x)= \begin{cases} 
       x^3+x^2  & x \geq -1  \\
      -x^3-x^2 & x < -1 \\
   \end{cases}
$$
My guess is that since both pieces are polynomials that $f(x)$ is smooth and thus the infinity differentiable everywhere.

I'm still wrapping my head around all this $C^1$ and $C^2$, smoothness, etc. So if anyone has any tips or tricks I'd love to know!

Thanks for your time!

Comment: How about computing $f'(-1)$?

Comment: This is your third question around the same topic. Did you read and understand the answered which you already got? –  You can proceed quite similarly as in your previous (answered) question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3691979/42969.

Comment: The Wikipedia article on "Smoothness" explains clearly what $C^0$, $C^1$, $C^2$ etc to $C^\infty$ are.

Comment: My apologies Martin, I'll stop.

Comment: By the way I think @MartinR point is not that you stop asking questions, but rather learn from the discussions in your previous questions and apply the same to answer similar questions. The problems are not difficult and you can come with at least some partial solutions on your own and try to get help here further.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The function $f$ is not differentiable at $-1$, since$$\lim_{x\to-1^+}\frac{f(x)-f(-1)}{x+1}=5$$and$$\lim_{x\to-1^-}\frac{f(x)-f(-1)}{x+1}=-5;$$therefore the limit $\lim_{x\to-1}\frac{f(x)-f(-1)}{x+1}$ doesn't exist. But $f$ is differentiable at every point $a\ne-1$ since:

- if $a>-1$, $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x^2(x+1)-a^2(a+1)}{x-a}=3a^2+2a$;
- if $a<-1$, $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{-x^2(x+1)+a^2(a+1)}{x-a}=-3a^2-2a$;

Comment: If one already knows that the function is differentiable in an open interval its an overkill to calculate the limit of the difference quotients because one can use the derivative of the function. The OP apparently knows that polynomials are differentiable.